# Recalculated downloader QoS values & Current full block not old enough

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I'm trying to build the private network between two raspberrry Pi3B with Geth.
But when i started the node and entered the javascript console,
it keeps showing the following message, and i don't know how to solve it:

```
Recalculated downloader QoS values
Current full block not old enough
```

also, when I wanna add another raspberry Pi by `admin.addPeer(enode)`, it's not work.

the following is the inform of the geth and my raspberry:

```
Version: 1.9.25-stable
Git Commit: e7872729012a4871397307b12cc3f4772ffcbec6
Git Commit Date: 20201211
Architecture: arm
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.15.6
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=/root/go
GOROOT=/root/.go
```

I build the private chain with the following genesis:

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 15312,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 15,
      "epoch": 30000
}
},
  "difficulty": "1",
  "gasLimit": "8000000",
  "extradata": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004c24e671f73bC1d110ee1Ff25d91ECa0Fb5630530000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "4c24e671f73bC1d110ee1Ff25d91ECa0Fb563053": { "balance": "3000" },
    "54610563D62F3a88CCAEfD6eFD391FE96d4A4c47": { "balance": "4000" }
}
}
```

and I started the node with the following command:

```
geth --identity "ETH-ViceNode" --rpc --rpcport "6060" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --datadir /home/pi/chain/data --port 30305 --networkid 15312 --verbosity 4 --nodiscover console

geth --identity "ETH-MainNode" --rpc --rpcport "6060" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --datadir /home/pi/chain/data --port 30304 --networkid 15312 --verbosity 4 --nodiscover console
```

anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am migrating my project to the docker and currently my node stops on generating DAG with same messages. Private chain deployment without docker could be found here if you or another reader looks for working use case https://github.com/Gelassen/swap